# How to read a local json file and display

Tags: xamarin.forms

newbie here,I could not find any example on Xamarin Forms read a local json file and display it. I need to do a local testing to read the local Json file.

1) Where do I save the json file for reading? in Android and iOS Projects or just in PCL project?

2) How to read the file?

here the code but it is not complete as I dont how to read the file.

```
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
{


var json = reader.ReadToEnd();

var rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);

whateverArray  = rootobject.Whatever;

}
```

The code miss the Path and others which required.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/

does offer a pretty good overview.

Comment: I read that before as well as the sample. It is not the normal Xaml and xaml.cs app. I am new and need some help to see how it work. var assembly = typeof(LoadResourceText).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WorkingWithFiles.PCLTextResource.txt"); is this applied to Andorid and iOS ??

Comment: it depends on what the build action of your file is. if it is an embedded resource you can read it like that ({assemblyName}.{foldersSeparatedWithDots}.{fileName} is the structure of the string to read it i think)

Comment: Local file is embedded resource. Mono.Droid and Mono.Touch have their own filesystem. Now, Xamarin Forms is diff again. Thus, I need to depend on XF sample to follow.

Comment: In that case the "Loading Files Embedded as Resources" in the above link is exactly what you need. You could download their sample code (top right links) and fiddle around with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can directly add your JSON file in PCL. Then change *build action* to *Embedded Resource*

Now you can read Json data by:

```
    var assembly = typeof("<ContentPageName>").GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Your_File.json");

    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
        {

            var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var data= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json);
        }
```

Comment: What is this LoadResourceText? I dont have this.

Comment: It's your contentPage name, idea is to get the assembly info first

Comment: Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Your_File.json"); - this line returns null for me. Any idea why?

Comment: I found out the error. We have to give the path as it is inside GetManifestResourceStream(), not only the file name.

Comment: I added following: assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.Your_File.json"); to get  correct name to file. The file is located directly under the project

Comment: What is "<ContentPageName>"?

Comment: <ContentPageName> is the name of Page in which You are trying to read Json File

Comment: Simply put, it's the class name from which you are getting the file.